# How to build SSRS report with Headers in Japanese Text

Tags: text, reporting-services, label, report

I'm creating a multi-lingual application. In which i will be generating report with the help of SSRS. Based on user language preference i can point to different report.

For English i point to Report.rdl
For Japanese i point to ReportJP.rdl

Now my question is, how i can put Japanese text for the static headers/labels.

When i try to copy Japanese text it is getting as square box.

I tried opening report in XML and replacing Label text with Japanese text, when i turn to design view is showing as square box.

Comment: Possible duplicate / solution... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282921/multilanguage-in-ssrs

Comment: Sorry, the link does not answer my problem. I'm trying out a simple solution: Two Report file one for English and another for Japanese. In Japanese Report file (.RDL) i'm just trying to put Japanese Headers in place of English Headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this issue which is very simple. Just set font of your text box/text/label to "MS PGothic". You will be able to see Japanese Text and can be exported to PDF, Excel etc.